# How to search data from Database using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to query data from database but want to use linq and also check data is null or not and have to use Contains function.

Actually i am sending data from a form then it should be check weather title contains this or not but i am getting error of null

```
var SearchTile = db.Job.Where(c => c.Title.Contains(Jobserach)).ToList();
```

[image]

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint to see which part of the code is throwing the null ref exception. There's very little information here.

Comment: Check the Image actually it returning null value

Comment: var check = db.Job.ToList();
            var SerachTile = check.Where(c => c.Title.Contains(Jobserach));

Comment: First check if the field names match between the database and your code.  Second check if the fields in the database allow nulls.  The database may contain nulls which is giving the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var check = db.Job.ToList();
var SerachTile = check.Where(c => c.Title.Contains(Jobserach));
```

Comment: Do you mind adding some explanation as to how this solves the problem? Code-only answers are frowned upon.